# Why regex pattern doesn't match with text?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, cron

i have a regex pattern and i want to match it with my cron-expression:

```
string pattern = @"(((([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])(-([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))?,)*([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])(-([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))?)|(([\\*]|[0-9]|[0-5][0-9])/([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))|([\\?])|([\\*]))[\\s](((([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])(-([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))?,)*([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])(-([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))?)|(([\\*]|[0-9]|[0-5][0-9])/([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))|([\\?])|([\\*]))[\\s](((([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])(-([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]))?,)*([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])(-([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]))?)|(([\\*]|[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])/([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]))|([\\?])|([\\*]))[\\s](((([1-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])(-([1-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]))?,)*([1-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])(-([1-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]))?(C)?)|(([1-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])/([1-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])(C)?)|(L(-[0-9])?)|(L(-[1-2][0-9])?)|(L(-[3][0-1])?)|(LW)|([1-9]W)|([1-3][0-9]W)|([\\?])|([\\*]))[\\s](((([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2])(-([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]))?,)*([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2])(-([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]))?)|(([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2])/([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]))|(((JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))?,)*(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))?)|((JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)/(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))|([\\?])|([\\*]))[\\s]((([1-7](-([1-7]))?,)*([1-7])(-([1-7]))?)|([1-7]/([1-7]))|(((MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(-(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?,)*(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(-(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?(C)?)|((MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)/(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(C)?)|(([1-7]|(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?(L|LW)?)|(([1-7]|MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)#([1-7])?)|([\\?])|([\\*]))([\\s]?(([\\*])?|(19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9]))?| (((19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9]))/((19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9])))?| ((((19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9]))(-((19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9])))?,)*((19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9]))(-((19[7-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9])))?)?)";
  string text = "0 0 0 ? APR,MAY * 2020,2021,2022"
  Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);

//the match output is: "0 0 0 ? APR,MAY *";
```

patter doesn't the years i just couldn't figure it out why.

Edited: Sorry for javascript tag on previous post now i want to explain why i did like that.It is a c# in .net project and i wanted to check this in frontend so i was thoughtfulness and that's why i put the javascript tag. Sorry this was may bad.
About to subject: I have a cron expression like seen upper in "string text" variable. I want to check if given cron expression is valid. We can think cron expression has 7 fields
 "Second Minute Hour DayOfMount Month DayOfWeek Year"
all fields have a space in between.The string pattern cover all but years.

Comment: Is this JavaScript code? If it is, is it valid syntax?

Comment: Looks like C# to me. Either way, I'm unclear on what's being asked here... more clarification would be great from OP (thanks).

Comment: what is it that you are trying to capture from regex can you, explain that please?

Comment: `Regex.Match` and the `@` prefix are from .net. Please tag your question appropriately

Answer (score 1):

The expression is written/generated for POSIX regex engines. POSIX engines tries to match the longest submatch.

C# is a .NET language, and uses a PCRE based engine. It tries to match the leftmost submatch.

For example, the pattern `[0-9]|[0-5][0-9]` will in POSIX engines try to match "59" over "5". PCRE engines tries to match the leftmost, so it will only try the `[0-9]` alternative, and stop when it succeeds.

In your pattern, the order of the alternatives are non-optimal, and sometimes wrong, for a PCRE based engine. Here is a rewritten pattern:

```
( #1
    (
        ([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])
        (-([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]))?
        ,
    )*
    ([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])
    (-([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]))?
  | ([*]|[0-5][0-9]|[0-9])
    \/
    ([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])
  | [?]
  | [*]
)
[\s]
( #2
    (
        ([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])
        (-([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]))?
        ,
    )*
    ([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])
    (-([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]))?
  | ([*]|[0-5][0-9]|[0-9])
    \/
    ([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])
  | [?]
  | [*]
)
[\s]
( #3
    (
        ([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9])
        (-([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9]))?
        ,
    )*
    ([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9])
    (-([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9]))?
  | ([*]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9])
    \/
    ([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9])
  | [?]
  | [*]
)
[\s]
( #4
    (
        ([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9])
        (-([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9]))?
        ,
    )*
    ([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9])
    (-([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9]))?
    C?
  | ([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9])
    \/
    ([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9])
    C?
  | LW
  | L(-([1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[0-9]))?
  | [1-3][0-9]W
  | [1-9]W
  | [?]
  | [*]
)
[\s]
( #5
    (
        (0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])
        (-(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9]))?
        ,
    )*
    (0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])
    (-(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9]))?
  | (0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])
    \/
    (0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])
  | (
        (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)
        (-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))?
        ,
    )*
    (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)
    (-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))?
  | (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)
    \/
    (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)
  | [?]
  | [*]
)
[\s]
( #6
    (
        [1-7]
        (-[1-7])?
        ,
    )*
    [1-7]
    (-[1-7])?
  | [1-7]\/[1-7]
  | (
        (MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)
        (-(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?
        ,
    )*
    (MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)
    (-(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?
    C?
  | (MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)
    \/
    (MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)
    C?
  | ([1-7]|MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)
    [#]
    [1-7]
  | ([1-7]|MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)
    (LW|L)?
  | [?]
  | [*]
)
( #7
    [\s]
    (
        (19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])
        (-(19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9]))?
        ,
    )*
    (19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])
    (-(19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9]))?
  | [\s]
    (19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])
    \/
    (19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])
  | [\s]
    [*]
)?
```

Or condensed into a string:

```
var pattern = @"((([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])(-([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]))?,)*([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])(-([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]))?|([*]|[0-5][0-9]|[0-9])\/([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])|[?]|[*])[\s]((([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])(-([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]))?,)*([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])(-([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]))?|([*]|[0-5][0-9]|[0-9])\/([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])|[?]|[*])[\s]((([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9])(-([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9]))?,)*([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9])(-([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9]))?|([*]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9])\/([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|[0-9])|[?]|[*])[\s]((([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9])(-([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9]))?,)*([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9])(-([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9]))?C?|([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9])\/([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9])C?|LW|L(-([1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[0-9]))?|[1-3][0-9]W|[1-9]W|[?]|[*])[\s](((0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])(-(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9]))?,)*(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])(-(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9]))?|(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])|((JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))?,)*(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))?|(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\/(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)|[?]|[*])[\s](([1-7](-[1-7])?,)*[1-7](-[1-7])?|[1-7]\/[1-7]|((MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(-(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?,)*(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(-(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?C?|(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)\/(MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)C?|([1-7]|MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)[#][1-7]|([1-7]|MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(LW|L)?|[?]|[*])([\s]((19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])(-(19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9]))?,)*(19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])(-(19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9]))?|[\s](19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])\/(19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])|[\s][*])?";
```

You might also want to add `^` at the start, and `$` at the end of the pattern. This makes sure there are no extra characters before or after the matched CRON expression.

```
var pattern = @"^((([0-5] ... [\s][*])?$";
```

Comment: It worked thank you very much. I up voted your commend but it says it requires at least 15 reputation for publicly displayed.